# Milnor fibration for non-isolated singularities

Tags: reference-request

Can someone provide a precise reference/statement of the fibration theorem for non-isolated singularities? So given $f:\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}$, and an $x\in Sing(f)$, what exactly does the fibration theorem say about the local structure of $f$ around $x$? Of course for isolated singularities there is Milnor's well known book, but for the non-isolated case I cannot find a reference.

Comment: Dung Tráng Lê, Some remarks on relative monodromy, Real and complex singularities (Proc. Ninth Nordic Summer School/NAVF Sympos. Math., Oslo, 1976), Sijthoff and Noordhoff, Alphen aan den Rijn, 1977, pp. 397– 403. MR 0476739 (57 #16296)

Comment: Maybe also J. L. Cisneros-Molina, J. Seade, and J. Snoussi, Refinements of Milnor’s fibration theorem for complex singularities, Adv. Math. 222 (2009), no. 3, 937– 970. MR 2553374 (2010k:32042)

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Thanks! The first book seems very difficult to find unfortunately. Since I am mostly interested in ambient space being $\mathbb{C}^n$, in particular smooth, is it fair to say that: 1) Milnor showed completely generally that $f/|f|:S_\epsilon\setminus Z(f)\to S^1$ is a fibration (without assumption on $f$) 2) Milnor showed that the fibers of $f/|f|$ are diffeomorphic to $f^{-1}(\delta)\cap B_\epsilon$ for small $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ (again in full generality) 3) Others showed that $f:B_\epsilon\setminus Z(f)\to B_\delta$ is a fibration in general